# Can I transform this GraphQL API request to a format which can be used in Python as json?

Tags: python, json, formatting, graphql

i am a noob in this area and need some help.

I did a GraphQL query with the Github v4 API using following code to filter search repositories. However I am not satisfied with the output format.

```
query {
  search(
    type:REPOSITORY, 
    query: """
      stars:<1000
      forks:>10
      size:>2000
      pushed:>=2019-08-01
      created:>=2018-08-01

    """,
    last: 100
  ) {
    repos: edges {
      repo: node {
        ... on Repository {
          name
          description
          url
          owner{__typename}
          licenseInfo{name}
          watchers{watchers: totalCount}
          releases {releases: totalCount}
          forks: forkCount
          pullRequests {pullRequests: totalCount}
          stargazers {stars: totalCount}
          openIssues: issues(states:OPEN){totalCount}
          totalIssues: issues {totalIssues: totalCount}
          primaryLanguage {primaryLanguage: name}
          languages(first: 3) { nodes {name} }
          repositoryTopics(first: 3) {nodes {topic {name}}}
          createdAt
          pushedAt
          updatedAt

       }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I would like to do is to import the query as .json so I can use it in Python.

I tried following approach in python but I am struggling with the json format

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.github.com/graphql'
json = {'query': '{stars:<1000} {forks:>10} {size:>2000 {pushed:>=2019-08-01} {created:>=2018-08-01}}'}
api_token = "abc.."
headers = {'Authorization': 'token %s' % api_token}

r = requests.post(url=url, json=json, headers=headers)
print (r.text)
```

Comment: It is easier with the [graphql-python/gql](https://github.com/graphql-python/gql) library now.